# after clicking submit button a white page appears

Tags: php, html, css

I have made form using HTML n CSS and also linked `action` to my PHP file  `index_handler.php` just don't understand where is the mistake that a strange white screen appears when I press `submit`

```
<form action="index_handler.php" class="appointment-form ftco-animate" method="post" name="form">
                        <div class="d-md-flex">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Full Name ">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group ml-md-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="m_name" placeholder="Mother's Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group ml-md-4">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email ID">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-md-flex">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-field">
                                    <div class="select-wrap">
                                       <div class="icon"><span class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></span></div>
                                       <select name="course" id="" class="form-control">
                                       <option value="text" style="color:black" >Select Course</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >Regular Classroom Programme</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >Distance Learning Programme</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >Online Learning Programme</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >School Integrated Programme</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >Crash Course Programme</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >Summer Course Programme</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >Edu-Nexus Programme</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-field">
                                    <div class="select-wrap">
                                       <div class="icon"><span class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></span></div>
                                       <select name="board" id="" class="form-control">
                                       <option value="text" style="color:black" >&nbsp; &nbsp; Board</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >CBSE</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >CHSE(STATE)</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >ICSE</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                                                            
                                
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-field">
                                    <div class="select-wrap">
                                       <div class="icon"><span class="ion-ios-arrow-down"></span></div>
                                       <select name="class" id="" class="form-control">
                                       <option value="text" style="color:black" >&nbsp; &nbsp;Class</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >VI</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >VII</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >VIII</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >IX</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >X</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >XI</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >XII</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >XIII</option>
                                            <option value="text" style="color:black" >Others</option>
                                       </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="d-md-flex">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <textarea name="address" id="" cols="30" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                
                            <div class="form-group ml-md-4">
                                <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
                            </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group ml-md-4">
                                  <input type="submit" value="Request A Quote" class="btn btn-secondary py-3 px-4">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </form>
```

**so here is my PHP file i.e, index_handler.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $m_name=$_POST['m_name'];
        $course=$_POST['course'];
        $board=$_POST['board'];
        $class=$_POST['class'];
        $address=$_POST['address'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];

        $to='rajkishore.panda2000@gmail.com'; 
        $subject='Form Submission';
        $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Mother's Name :".$m_name."\n"."Course :".$course."\n"."Board :".$board."\n"."Class :".$class."\n"."Phone :".$phone."\n"."Address:"."\n\n".$address;
        $headers="From: ".$email;

        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo "<h1>Sent Successfully! Thank you"." ".$name.", We will contact you shortly!</h1>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<h1>Something went wrong!</h1>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need to give your submit button a name. name="submit"

Comment: exactly bro ! just overlooked Thank you soo much ! but meanwhile I got a new problem its working properly but only 1st two fields `name` and `n_name` is coming in mail..rest others are not. Any solutions for that?

Comment: Add this to the top it display all errors and do a `var_dump($_POST);` to make sure you have all your names correct. `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need give submit button name, because your php is

```
isset($_POST['submit'])
```

to fix your problem, change your code

```
<input type="submit" value="Request A Quote" class="btn btn-secondary py-3 px-4">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Request A Quote" class="btn btn-secondary py-3 px-4">
```

Comment: Hey Lexa ! just overlooked that ..Thank you soo much ! but meanwhile I got a new problem its working properly but only 1st two fields `name` and `n_name`  are coming in mail..rest others are not. Any solutions for that?

Comment: can you share some screenshoot about your second problem  ?

Comment: [link](http://isa-com.stackstaging.com)  you will find the form here.. what I mean to say is when you fill the form.. the e-mail received  contains only first 2 fields that is _Full Name_ and _Mother's name_......the **option values** are not coming

Comment: check variable name is correct, use var_dump($_POST);die; in index_handler.php

Answer (score 0):

Hey just Add name="submit" and that's it
change this code

```
<div class="form-group ml-md-4">
                                  <input type="submit" value="Request A Quote" class="btn btn-secondary py-3 px-4">
                                </div>
```

To be

```
<div class="form-group ml-md-4">
                                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Request A Quote" class="btn btn-secondary py-3 px-4">
                                </div>
```